# I have nodejs bot deployed it on azure and I want to authenticate all the user with azure active directory

Tags: node.js, botframework

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-dotnet-lob-application-azure-ad/#configure-authentication-and-directory-access
I have done the azure side configurationb by this document but which part should i add to my bot and get the access token from
https://microsoftluisbot.azurewebsites.net/.auth/me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your timeframe and if you want to do it yourself; you will have to take a look to [passport.js](http://passportjs.org/), specifically to the [Azure Ad strategy](https://github.com/AzureAD/passport-azure-ad).

If you are not in a rush, then you might want to wait until the node.js version of [AuthBot](https://github.com/matvelloso/authbot) is ready. Based on this [post](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/1387), it seems Mat is already working on it.

## Update Nov-28

A preliminary version of AuthBot for Node.js can be found at https://github.com/CatalystCode/node-authbot/

Comment: do you tell me the expected time

Comment: I don't know know the time. You can ask Mat in that thread in GitHub if you want. Please accept the answer if it was useful.

Comment: FYI, here is a preliminary version of AuthBot for node: https://github.com/CatalystCode/node-authbot/